# What "the" does in Haskell and how it can be used?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell there are several type definitions for `the` which I can't put together in my mind to make sense of it, do these definitions share a common purpose? if so what is it?
i.e some from Hoggle:

```
the :: Eq a => [a] -> a

the :: HasAny sel s t a b => Lens s t a b

the :: (Eq a, Monad m) => SerialT m a -> m (Maybe a)
```

etc.

Comment: Like in (almost) every language, modules in Haskell are effectively namespaced so library creators do not have to worry about names clashing with those in other libraries (or those yet to be written). We basically have 3 separate functions for which the library authors (presumably different in each case) decided `the` was an appropriate name - and they likely have nothing in common beyond that name. If you see code using one the import statements should make it clear which one. (This seems an odd question to ask on SO, and I'm surprised that people have bothered to answer and by the upvotes!)

Comment: @RobinZigmond odd or not, I'm glad I asked, rather than leaving myself with the doubt. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 8):

The first `the` "ensures" all elements in a list are equal (hence `Eq`) and panics otherwise. Its name is because it gives you "the" only element up to equality in the list.

```hs
>>> the [1, 2, 3]
Error
>>> the [1, 1, 1]
1
```

The second `the` is used to construct a lens (something that can "extract" a part of a data). For example, you can use `the @"name"` to make a lens that takes the `name` field of a record type. Or `the @Int` to extract the only `Int` value in a data, or `the @3` to get the third component of a data.

```hs
data Human = Human
  { name    :: String
  , age     :: Int
  , address :: String
  }
  deriving (Generic, Show)
human :: Human
human = Human "Tunyasz" 50 "London"

>>> human ^. the @Int
50
>>> human ^. the @"name"
"Tunyasz"
>>> human ^. the @3
"London"
```

The third function is similar to the first but works for a stream in the library `streamly` instead of for a list, and returns `None` instead of panic when the elements are not identical.

Comment: Then there is no relation between these functions just happen to have the same name defined in different ext namespaces as @RobinZigmond pointed out?

Answer (score 5):

The different definitions that you're referring to come from different modules in different packages: The first is from `GHC.Exts` in `base` and the third is from `streamly` in both of which it is used to ensure that a list only contains one value, returning that value; the second is from `Data.Generics.Product.Any` in `generic-lens`, in which it is used to select something from a Lens.